# Zero One laws on Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,..$ be i.i.d. exponential$(\lambda)$. Show that there exists $C_0$ such that $C<C_0$ implies $\mathbb{P}\{X_n \geq C\:\log n \:\:\text{i.o.}\}=1$ and $C>C_0$ implies $\mathbb{P}\{X_n \geq C\:\log n\:\: \text{i.o.}\}=0$.

Comment: Please give your thoughts on the problem such as what you've tried and where you're stuck. What does Borel Cantelli say?

Comment: $P(X > x) = e^{-\lambda x},$ not $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ and the math on the next line is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

Let $C= k/\lambda.$ Then $$ P(X_n \geq C\log n) = n^{-k}.$$ Now apply Borel-Cantelli to tell you for what values of $k$ infinitely many of the events happen almost surely.